# Obteniendo datos con orWhere

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente función que me recoge los datos de los libros que he comprado. Ciertamente funciona, cuando busco por los tres parámetros me da lo que quiero y cuando no uso los parámetros me da lo que busco también. 
La cosa es que lo hago por código php y yo sabría hacerlo en forma de sql sin tener que hacer dos consultas, pero NO se hacerlo en Eloquent, el hecho de que se busque por una query o por otra en sql sería con un or, pero en este caso al poner el or solo busca por uno de ellos y el otro ni lo toca.

Y lo que quiero preguntar es: ¿no hay un método mejor para recoger los libros que tengan un usuario actual O recoger los libros que tenga el usuario actual con los parámetros que le vienen dados?

```
public function comprados(Request $request){

        $query= trim($request->get('searchText'));

        $gLit= trim($request->get('gLit'));

    $gArt= trim($request->get('gArt'));

    $usuario_actual=\Auth::user();

    $libros=DB::table('libro as l')
        ->join('lineapedido as lp', 'lp.lpe_libro_id', '=', 'l.id_libro')
        ->join('autor as a', 'a.id_autor', '=', 'l.lib_autor_id')
        ->join('generoartistico as ga', 'ga.id_generoartistico', '=', 'a.atr_genero_artistico_id')
        ->join('generoliterario as gl', 'gl.id_generoliterario', '=', 'l.lib_genero_literario_id')
        ->join('pedido as ped', 'ped.id_pedido', '=', 'lp.lpe_pedido_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as mismolibro'), 'l.id_libro', 'l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
            'l.lib_imagen', 'a.atr_nombre_artistico as autor', 'gl.gl_nombre as generoliterario',
            'ga.ga_nombre as generoartistico')
        ->orwhere(function($query2) use ($query, $gLit, $gArt, $usuario_actual) {
            $query2->where('lib_titulo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->where('id_generoliterario', '=', $gLit)
                ->where('id_generoartistico', '=', $gArt)
                ->where('ped.ped_cliente_id', '=', $usuario_actual->u_cliente_id);
        })
        ->groupBy('id_libro','l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
            'l.lib_imagen', 'a.atr_nombre_artistico', 'gl.gl_nombre',
            'ga.ga_nombre')
        ->paginate(7);

    if($gLit==null && $gArt==null && $query==null)
    {
        $libros=DB::table('libro as l')
            ->join('lineapedido as lp', 'lp.lpe_libro_id', '=', 'l.id_libro')
            ->join('autor as a', 'a.id_autor', '=', 'l.lib_autor_id')
            ->join('generoartistico as ga', 'ga.id_generoartistico', '=', 'a.atr_genero_artistico_id')
            ->join('generoliterario as gl', 'gl.id_generoliterario', '=', 'l.lib_genero_literario_id')
            ->join('pedido as ped', 'ped.id_pedido', '=', 'lp.lpe_pedido_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as mismolibro'), 'l.id_libro', 'l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
                'l.lib_imagen', 'a.atr_nombre_artistico as autor', 'gl.gl_nombre as generoliterario',
                'ga.ga_nombre as generoartistico')
            ->where('ped.ped_cliente_id', '=', $usuario_actual->u_cliente_id)

            ->groupBy('id_libro','l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
                'l.lib_imagen', 'a.atr_nombre_artistico', 'gl.gl_nombre',
                'ga.ga_nombre')
            ->paginate(7);
    }

    $generoart=GeneroArtistico::all();
    $generolit=GeneroLiterario::all();

    return view('almacen.libro.comprados', ["libros"=>$libros, "searchText" => $query, "generoart"=> $generoart, "generolit"=> $generolit, "gLit"=> $gLit, "gArt"=> $gArt]);
}
```

Lo que yo querría es que la siguiente consulta funcionara, pero sin embargo cuando busco por los parámetros $gLit, $gArt, y $query me hace caso omiso y simplemente busca por el where:

```
$libros=DB::table('libro as l')
            ->join('lineapedido as lp', 'lp.lpe_libro_id', '=', 'l.id_libro')
            ->join('autor as a', 'a.id_autor', '=', 'l.lib_autor_id')
            ->join('generoartistico as ga', 'ga.id_generoartistico', '=', 'a.atr_genero_artistico_id')
            ->join('generoliterario as gl', 'gl.id_generoliterario', '=', 'l.lib_genero_literario_id')
            ->join('pedido as ped', 'ped.id_pedido', '=', 'lp.lpe_pedido_id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as mismolibro'), 'l.id_libro', 'l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
                'l.lib_imagen', 'a.atr_nombre_artistico as autor', 'gl.gl_nombre as generoliterario',
                'ga.ga_nombre as generoartistico')
            ->where('ped.ped_cliente_id', '=', $usuario_actual->u_cliente_id)
            ->orwhere(function($query2) use ($query, $gLit, $gArt, $usuario_actual) {
                $query2->where('lib_titulo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                    ->where('id_generoliterario', '=', $gLit)
                    ->where('id_generoartistico', '=', $gArt)
                    ->where('ped.ped_cliente_id', '=', $usuario_actual->u_cliente_id);
            })
            ->groupBy('id_libro','l.lib_no', 'l.lib_titulo', 'l.lib_direccion_web', 'l.lib_fecha_creacion',
                'l.lib_imagen', 'a.atr_nombre_artistico', 'gl.gl_nombre',
                'ga.ga_nombre')
            ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien por que razón no querés usar Eloquent. ¿Podrías explicarmelo un poco mejor?, creo poder ayudarte pero realmente tu código me lleva a desistir en mi intento.   
Se me complica incluso entender que es lo que estas necesitando hacer.  
En principio puedo notar que en el bloque donde calculas $libros usas un `orWhere()` antes de haber usado un `where()` antes.  
La verdad me gustaría en serio saber por que NO Eloquent y despues exactamente que es lo que querés hacer

Comment: Quiero usar Eloquent, lo que pasa es que no se como hacerlo en este caso y por eso uso la clase BD, seguidamente lo que yo quiero hacer es que en la query se pregunte por ->where('ped.ped_cliente_id', '=', $usuario_actual->u_cliente_id) y además por ->orwhere(function($query2) use ($query, $gLit, $gArt, $usuario_actual) {->where('lib_titulo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->where('id_generoliterario', '=', $gLit)
                ->where('id_generoartistico', '=', $gArt)...}) pero cuando le introduzco las variables $gLit ... las ignora y simplemente busca por ped_cliente_id

Comment: Con lo de NO Eloquent lo que quiero decir es que no se cómo hacer eso en Eloquent, pero si con la clase DB.

Comment: Lo que te recomiendo es que estudies un poco mas de la [relaciones en laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships), ya que en mi opinion haces demaciado codigo para algo que en laravel se hacen de forma muy sencilla

Comment: No entiendo por qué quieres buscar todos los libros de X cliente y también los libros de X cliente pero con ciertos parámetros. ¿No sería solo una de las dos búsquedas según si hay parámetros o no?

Comment: Serían ambas búsquedas si hay parámetros, porque estoy buscando por el usuario ese y que tenga además esos otros parámetros, pero si no tiene parámetros solo busca por el usuario ese.

Comment: Pero si analizas tu lógica, habría un error, porque al decirle que traiga TODOS los libros de ese usuario, implícitamente estarías incluyendo aquellos que tengan parámetros.

Comment: Tratemos de pasar a una oración o un parrafo lo que vos querés hacer:  
Suele ser un buen ejercicio.  
Puede ser que (en primer termino) quieras un listado de los libros que tiene comprados el usuario autenticado?

Comment: Exacto Maru, y si tengo las variables quiero que me busque por el usuario autentificado y dichas variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a proporcionar una respuesta basada en Laravel 5.5+ y en las relaciones de Eloquent, además del estándar de estilo de código PSR-2.

El problema radica en que orWhere() no sirve para lo que tú necesitas, pues este va a entregar el "agregado" de los resultados de los dos where.

La solución es hacer condicionales para definir qué query realizar, con when(), el cual recibe como primer parámetro un boolean, el segundo es lo que se ejecutará si es verdadero, y el tercero lo que se ejecutará si es falso:

```
public function comprados(Request $request)
{

    $query = $request->searchText;
    $gLit = $request->gLit;
    $gArt = $request->gArt;
    $usuarioActual = auth()->user();

    $filteredQuery = !empty($query) && !empty($gLit) && !empty(gArt);

    $libros = Libro::with(['lineas', 'generos', 'autor', 'pedidos']) // las relaciones implicadas
              ->when($filteredQuery, function ($q) use ($query, $gLit, $gArt, $usuarioActual) {
                  $q->whereIdGeneroliterario($gLit);
                  $q->whereIdGeneroartistico($gArt);
                  $q->where('lib_titulo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
                  $q->wherePedClienteId($usuarioActual->u_cliente_id);
              }, function ($q) use ($usuarioActual) {
                  $q->wherePedClienteId($usuarioActual->u_cliente_id);
              })
              ->paginate(7);

    $generoArt = GeneroArtistico::all();
    $generoLit = GeneroLiterario::all();
    $searchtext = $query;

    return view('almacen.libro.comprados', compact('libros', 'searchText', 'generoLit', 'generoArt', 'gLit', 'gArt');
}
```

El resto simplemente es adaptarlo a tus necesidades, como los conteos.

Comment: Siempre sabes como resolver mis problemas, muchas gracias lo usaré!